# writing an enumerated list within a sentence

Tags: enumerate, inline

Can you please help me write an enumerated list which is in the same line and there is no line change between that and the rest of the text. E.g.,

> We use three broad geographical regions, i.e., (i) the U.S., (ii)
>   current EU-27 countries, and (iii) all remaining countries.

Comment: See, for instance, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Inline_lists

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly. I had to download a package. Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 4):

With `enumitem` it is easy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  We use three broad geographical regions,
  \begin{enumerate*}[label=(\roman*),before=\unskip{ i.e., }, itemjoin={{, }}, itemjoin*={{, and }}]
  \item the U.S.
  \item current EU-27 countries
  \item all remaining countries.
  \end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all. I have some reservations since I've tried Jubobs  suggestion but something goes wrong. I use TexStudio. Maybe this is a problem. But many thanks anyway :)

Comment: @veni Well, did you try Harish Kumar's suggestion? Rest assured, TeXStudio is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late to the party but another solution that is really clean and easy to use is the `paralist` package.

A quick example of it:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}
This includes:
\begin{inparaenum}[(i)]
\item first task,
\item second task and
\item third task
\end{inparaenum}
to be completed by the end of the month.
\end{document}
```

This will come out as:

This includes: (i) first task, (ii) second task and (iii) third task to be
completed by the end of the month.

More can be found here
https://texblog.org/2013/02/01/inline-lists-in-latex-using-paralist/