# Properly writing an enumerated list in different lines within a sentence

Tags: formatting, lists, enumerate, best-practices

My question is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236613/writing-an-enumerated-list-within-a-sentence) but my items are bigger so I would like to write my items each in a different line. I am currently doing as follows

```
The way to propose a solution that
\begin{enumerate}
    \item is able to clearly show my items,
    \item can be read as if it were only one sentence, and
    \item is well formatted
\end{enumerate}
is presented here.
```

It is rendering like this

[image]

. Could I make it any better? Are there any rules for this type of structure? Is it preferable to put it all in one line or it would be more personal taste?

Comment: I think this may be what you are looking for,http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135726/intertext-like-command-in-enumerate-environment  however a MWE and clear statement of what is wanted would help.

Comment: I don't want to put text between items of a list, just a list in a sentence. It is more about best practices/serious document formatting (I don't do this often) than trying to use the markup language to accomplish something I know exactly how it would look like. The example I've shown is similar to my original text, but mine has 5 items.

Comment: Understand.  Now I would suggest that you consult the style guide that you are using.  If not, then I would suggest that you choose a style guide common to your field of study and master it.   Each of the guide differ on how best to handle lists of phrases.  e.g. APA would want them to be parallel in structure and remain in a comma delimited sentence.   This site is a good initial comparison of some style on this topic. http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/punc-lists.html  And as for the style question, it might be better answered if asked in http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is off-topic as far as I can tell. I dare say it does depend on discipline but, at least in my discipline, it also depends on the type of document you are creating. Is this an article? Is it a handout? Is it teaching material? Is it a set of slides? (Other possibilities I've not thought of.) There is no one 'right' answer.

Comment: It is probably off-topic but I've got some useful answers/comments that I wouldn't get elsewhere

Comment: Off-topic. But this kind of writing is (unfortunately) common in statutory writing.  See, e.g., [this random example](https://www.canlii.org/en/on/laws/regu/rro-1990-reg-194/latest/#sec7.06subsec1). Re-write it if at all possible if it is part of a larger prose piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three possibilities, with `enumitem`s tools:

```
\documentclass{report}%{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

The way to propose a solution that
\begin{enumerate}[nosep, wide]
  \item is able to clearly show my items,
  \item can be read as if it were only one sentence, and
  \item is well formatted
\end{enumerate}
is presented here.

\bigskip

The way to propose a solution that
\begin{enumerate}[nosep, topsep=3pt, wide]
  \item is able to clearly show my items,
  \item can be read as if it were only one sentence, and
  \item is well formatted
\end{enumerate}
is presented here.

\bigskip

The way to propose a solution that
\begin{enumerate}[nosep, topsep=3pt, wide=0pt]
  \item is able to clearly show my items,
  \item can be read as if it were only one sentence, and
  \item is well formatted
\end{enumerate}
is presented here.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg: I know it's a bad example to write `\\` before a blank line — it was only because it I felt too lazy to write `\vskip{some length}` to clearly separate the three examples…

Comment: Don't be lazy with this: ``\\`` for “leaving a blank line” is one of the worst errors.

Comment: I meant adding some more  vertical spacing. The main point was to have clearly distinct examples, and it was of no consequence in the context ', except a very nasty example… ;o(